# PHP date insert using datepicker

Tags: php, mysql, sql, localhost

My PHP script writes "Data entered!", but there are no records in the database. Here is the code.

```
<?php
$startdate = $_POST['start'];
$enddate = $_POST['end'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

if ($startdate && $enddate && $type) {
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("Can not connect to DB"); 
mysqli_select_db($con,"booker")or die("Can not select DB");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO events(start_date,end_date,type) VALUES('$startdate','$enddate','$type')");
echo "Data entered!";
}
else {
echo "Please fill in the form!";
}


?>
```

I select dates using datepicker and type is selected through select option in html (3 options available). Names of html form fields are start, end, type. Fields in DB are start_date, end_date, type. PHP script runs with no errors and everything seems ok, but there are no records in DB.

Comment: i think u need to check date format what r u getting in `$_POST` then convert as MySQL needed like 'YYYY-MM-DD', if you are really using datatype `Date`, u also need to explore php error_reporting()

Comment: I think you need to test for errors, not just assume everything worked.

Comment: `echo "Data entered!";` does not mean, your INSERT executed successfully, bcoz this message will be displayed either query executed or not.

Comment: first of all share the result of `print_r($_POST)` what are u getting second, use this to get query error `die(mysqli_error($con)); ` third, your code is wide open for sql injection

Comment: I have checked connection for errors and it works, error message is shown when something changes. I also thought about date format, but should't I get all zeros in table instead of empty table?

Comment: To verify if the query was successfully executed try:

`mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO events(start_date,end_date,type) VALUES('$startdate','$enddate','$type')") or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: if u r getting all zero, it means, you are using DATE datatype but your date format is not correct.

Comment: share the result of `print_r($_POST)` and also share the datatype of your date columns..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send all dates you want to `INSERT` with SQL through `date()` like so:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What makes you think that this exact piece solves the problem?

Comment: OP could be having date filter issues if dates are not properly formatted to work in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your PHP script. It just comes from the input. Make sure you have a standard format like

```
"YYYY-MM-DD" (use - 'hypen').
```

MySql won't respond if you use outside of that format, for example

```
"YYYY/MM/DD" -> this won't work.
```